# Sampling Uniformity Factor

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling

I am not from the field of statistics but would like to inquire about a certain factor that pertains to the level of confidence of a certain pile grade.

For example:

In mining, extraction can be determined by looking at the deposit as *ore blocks*, 5m x 5m x 3m. A row of blocks constitutes to a bench. Face samples were obtained from each block to give initial classification. Blocks were extracted accordingly with classification, and usually, each bench has a similar classification. But within benches of the same classification, wide variation among face samples were observed.

After extraction, each truck of ore was sampled (one-point sampling) upon stockyard entry. Thirty (30) truck samples contribute to one (1) mine sample grade. All trucks with the same classification were dumped in the stockyard as one pile. As current practices by other companies, each pile grade was obtained using the arithmetic average of all the mine samples from the trucks on that pile. Like face sampling, truck samples for each pile have wide variations among sample grades.

After piling in the stockyard (warehousing), ore will be *blended* to achieve specifications desired for the shipment.

The problem lies in determining the "pile grade" before blending. Is there a way to determine a "uniformity factor" or a factor that can define how uniform each pile is using the previous sampling data from face sampling and truck sampling, that leads to the level of confidence of each pile?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a really interesting question. I suspect you won't get a whole lot of answers because although you've clearly made a great effort to write as informatively as possible, you also clearly have a specialised knowledge of the subject and it's a bit tricky to understand the context behind the problem.